# OpenGL 3.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux Mint 17.1) + Intel Graphics + LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, ubuntu, 3d, lwjgl

I am trying to run OpenGL software built with LWJGL and GLSL 3.3 but having trouble doing so under Linux Mint 17.1 and Intel Ivy Bridge (HD4000) + Mesa 10.6.0-devel.

From what I read Mesa 10.1+ should have support to OpenGL and GLSL 3.3 for Sandry Bridge and more recent Intel CPUs.

glxinfo | grep OpenGL returns:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-4348046 2015-05-02 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-4348046 2015-05-02 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-4348046 2015-05-02 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

(I'm guessing I need OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30, and not just Core Profile 3.3?)

When calling *Display.create()* (LWJGL) with no parameters I get the following error:

```
> 0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are:
> 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
```

and *glGetString(GL_VERSION)* returns:

```
> 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-4348046 2015-05-02 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
```

If I try to call *Display.create()* with core profile true, like so:

```
Display.create(new PixelFormat(), new ContextAttribs(3,3).withProfileCore(true));
```

I receive the following error:

```
0:11(6): error: operands of `==' must have the same type
```

and GL_VERSION is:

```
3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-4348046 2015-05-02 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
```

I'm not sure what this means or what should I do to be able to run OpenGL 3.3 on Intel integrated graphics. I'm positive this same code works on nVidia (4.4+ support).

Any help on this matter will be appreciated, thank you!

Edit: the shader that's causing the problem:

```
#version 330

in vec2 texCoord0;

uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main() {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sampler, texCoord0.xy);

    if (textureColor == 0)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1);
    else
        gl_FragColor = textureColor * vec4(color, 1);
}
```

Comparing **textureColor** *== vec4(0, 0, 0, 0)* did work, sorry.

I can run it now. But I don't see any of the textures. I will try to find the problem, is there anything obvious that could be causing this in my shader?

Comment: Mesa supports GL > 3.0 only in a core profile. You actually managed to get a core profile in your later attempts, and the GLSL compiler is now accepting the `#version 330` directive. However, your shader has some syntax error in line 11, as `0:11(6): error: operands of '==' must have the same type` is trying to tell you. You should post the shader source code. THe fact that the shader works on Nvidia is not really proving anything. Especially the nvidia compiler is very sloppy and allows lots of constructs which are beyond the GLSL spec.

Comment: Thank you, I will add the shaders to the original question. I assumed there was no problem with them since I can run this code on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite obvious, isn't it?

```
vec4 textureColor = ...
[...]
if (textureColor == 0)
```

You can't compare a `vec4` to a scalar. You could use somehting like `if (textureColor == vec4(0) )`.

However, comparing floating point values for equality is a bad idea in most cases. I really would recommend you use a different approach, like testing for `length(textureColor) < 0.5/256.0`.

Comment: Yes, I had changed that before your answer, thank you anyway!